# RDLC "wrap" report column

Tags: visual-studio, matrix, report, rdlc

How can I create a report in `RDLC` that has **3** columns with dynamic rows?

I have a `DataTable` which contains the car brands:

[image: DataTable car brands]

I would like to create a report where to split my list in **3** column *fixed* and *dynamic* rows.
Something like this:

[image: Result of report]

How I can convert my `DataTable` in this way? I've tried using a `Matrix`, but the data are entered in the columns and reached the limits of report don't wrap but continue to go and end up on the next page

Answer (score -1):

Use horizontal table with list break : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28532306/SSRS-horizontal-data-display-with-wrap-matrix.html

Comment: Please include the relevant code from your links since links may break and invalidate your answer.